Consider optimization problem with an equality constraint :
I am trying to solve a constrained optimization problem, it seems a bit confusing however, I have made an attempt
$$\text{minimize}\ xy + yz $$
$$\text{subject to }$$ $$y^2+ z^2 -1 =0  \\ 
                        xy -1 =0 \\
 (x,y,z) \in\mathbb{R}^{3}$$
$\text{My attempt}$
Question
a) Write the Lagrangian function of the problem
$ \text{Answer a) }$
$$L(x,y,z, \lambda_{1},  \lambda_{2}) = \underbrace{xy+yz}_{\text{objective function}}+  \lambda_{1}\underbrace{(y^2+z^2-1)}_{\text{contraint 1}}+ \lambda_{2}\underbrace{(xy-1)}_{\text{contraint 2}}$$
Question
b) Apply the first-order necessary conditions to determine the candidates for the local minimum
Answer b) In this I partially differentiate the lagrangean function w.r.t to  $x,y,z, \lambda_{1},  \lambda_{2}$ and set equal $0$
$$\\L_x=y+ \lambda_{2}y=0
\\L_y= x+z+ \lambda_{1}(2y)+\lambda_{2}(x)=0\\
L_z =y+\lambda_{1}(2z)=0\\
L_{\lambda_{1}} =y^2+z^2-1=0\\
L_{\lambda_{2}}=xy-1=0$$
$\text{from }$ $L_x=0$ $\text{we get}$
$$y(1+\lambda_{2})=0 \implies y = 0 ,\ \lambda_{2}=-1$$
$\text{Case 1:}$
$$\text{for y } = 0 , \text{the second constraint becomes } x= 1/y =1/0 \,\, \text{undefined}   $$
$\text{thus}  \, y = 0 \, \, \text{case is invalid } $
$\text{Case 2:}$
$\text{for  } \lambda_{2}=-1 \, \text{and} \,  y \neq 0 \, \text{Utilizing} \,L_y \, \text{and} \, L_z \, \text{we get : }$
$$L_y = z+ \lambda_{1}(2y)=0\\
L_z = y + \lambda_{1}(2z)=0$$
$\text{Making y the subject  from  }\, L_z\, , y = -\lambda_{1}(2z) \, \text{substituting in }\, L_y ,\,\text{we get}\:$
$$z\,(1-4 \lambda_{1}^2)=0 \implies z= 0 , \,\, \lambda_{1}^2=\frac{1}{4}$$
$ \text {Let's look into } z= 0 \text{ if we substitute it  into }L_y\,\,\text{we get}\,y =0\, \text{and into constraint 1 we get }\, y= \pm1 \, \text{invalid through contradiction.}  $
$\text{Using } \lambda_{1}^2=\frac{1}{4} \, \text{and}\, y = -\lambda_{1}(2z) \, 
\text{and Utilizing constraint 1 to find z : }\,  $
$$ (-\lambda_{1}(2z))^2 +z^2=1 \\
2z^2=1 \implies z = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$\text{Utilizing constraint 1 to find y } $
$$ y^2 +  \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2=1 \implies y = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$\text{Utilizing constraint 2 to find x} $
$$ x= \left(\frac{1}{y} \right) \implies x = \pm \sqrt{2} $$
So, possible candidates for local minimum are :
$\text{point 1 }\left(\sqrt{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)  $
$\text{point 2 }\left(-\sqrt{2}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)  $
$\text{point 3 }\left(\sqrt{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} , -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)  $
$\text{point 4 }\left(-\sqrt{2}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} , -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)  $
Question
c Find the corresponding Lagrange multipliers
Answer c ) For
$$\lambda_{2} = -1 \, \text{we get } \lambda_{1}^2=\frac{1}{4} \implies  \lambda_{1}=\pm \frac{1}{2}$$
Question
d) Study the matrix  $L(x_*)$ to determine the local minimum(a) of the problem.
$\text{Answer d ) } $
$$ H_L(x,y,z,\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1+\lambda_2 & 0 & 0 & y \\
1+\lambda_2 & 2\lambda_1 & 1 & 2y & x \\
0& 1 & 2\lambda_1 & 2z & 0 \\
0 & 2y & 2z & 0 & 0 \\
y & x & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
observation : For four candidates points found in b and for  $\lambda_1 = \pm1/2 , \lambda_2 = -1  \,\, H_L(x,y,z,\lambda_1, \lambda_2) \,$ The matrix has both positive and negative eigenvalues suggesting all the stationary points Or candidates  are saddle points.
*********************************                                end of attempt***********************************************************
Questions I have :
Q-1 Is my working correct in finding the candidates for local minima, have I considered all the cases?
Q-2 is the  Lagrange multipliers correct?
Q-3 Is hessian of the Lagrange function written correctly and
by plugging in the values in the matrix, I could conclude the candidates are all saddle points, it seems there are no local minima. is this possible or have I made some calculation error?
thank you in advance for Answering

I can't understand why this question was closed for "does not appear to be about math"

@BrianBorchers not sure, I had only added \text which led some to the words out of the margin and changed  formatting.
